# Grails: adding dynamic methods within a plugin

Tags: grails, metaprogramming, grails-plugin

I'm developing a plugin that adds a `getFlashHelper` method to each controller. This method should return an instance of a `FlashHelper` class.

However, the constructor of the `FlashHelper` class must be passed the *instance* of the controller on which the `getFlashHelper` method was called.

Hopefully the following code will explain what I'm doing a bit better

```
def doWithDynamicMethods = {ctx ->

    application.controllerClasses*.metaClass*.getFlashHelper = {

        def controllerInstance = delegate

        // Avoid creating a new FlashHelper each time the 'flashHelper' property is accessed
        if (!controllerInstance.metaClass.hasProperty('flashHelperInstance')) {
            controllerInstance.metaClass.flashHelperInstance = new FlashHelper(controller: controllerInstance)
        }

        // Return the FlashHelper instance. There may be a simpler way, but I tried
        // controllerInstance.metaClass.getMetaProperty('flashHelperInstance')
        // and it didn't work
        return controllerInstance.metaClass.getMetaProperty('flashHelperInstance').getter.invoke(controllerInstance, [] as Object[])
    }
}
```

The code appears to work, but I can't help feeling that there must be an easier way of doing this. That last line is particularly gruesome. Is there any way I can simplify this?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 1):

Since controllers are created per-request, I'd store the helper as a Request attribute:

```
for (c in grailsApplication.controllerClasses) {
   c.clazz.metaClass.getFlashHelper = { ->
      def controllerInstance = delegate
      def request = controllerInstance.request
      def helper = request['__flash_helper__']
      if (!helper) {
         helper = new FlashHelper(controller: controllerInstance)
         request['__flash_helper__'] = helper
      }
      helper
   }
}
```

Comment: If I use this approach I'll end up creating a lot more FlashHelper objects, i.e. one per request, instead of one per controller class. Notice that in the approach I've used, I create on FlashHelper per controller class/metaClass, not one per controller instance.

Is there some advantage to this approach that I'm missing, apart from the slightly more legible code?

Thanks!

Comment: In standard Spring MVC controllers are singletons, but in Grails a new controller instance is created for each request. So we're both creating the same number of helper instances. Add a println or a log statement to your getFlashHelper closure to verify.

Comment: But my approach will create one FlashHelper per Controller **class** (not one per controller instance), whereas yours will create one per request. I still don't see what the advantages of storing the FlashHelper as a request attribute, rather than a metaClass property are?

Comment: If you do create one per class then you've introduced a large bug since the helper needs the controller instance. After the first request your helper will have a reference to the previous controller instance which is no longer available (and now probably not available for garbage collection). But you're not, you're creating one per instance.